# Uploading files to Web api server from xamarin - Requests taking too long to process

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I'm using HttpClient to post a binary file to the server which is hosted by Azure. The request is taking to0 long to get across for files that aren't that big in size. Some times the server receives the request when the client has already cancelled the task due to time out. I'm uploading the data asynchronously using the below code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
{
    videoThumbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var progress = new System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler();

    progress.HttpSendProgress += progress_HttpSendProgress;

    using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalVariables.host);

        // Set the Accept header for BSON.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

        var request = new uploadFileModel { data = file, dateCreated = DateTime.Now, fileName = fileName, username = loggedUser, VideoThumbName = videoThumbName};

        // POST using the BSON formatter.
        MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        var m = client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize;
        var result = await client.PostAsync("api/media/upload", request, bsonFormatter);

        return result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

The server side code looks like this (I have left some code for brevity):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload(uploadFileModel model)
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string thumbname = model.VideoThumbName;
        string tempPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/video");
        string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/video"), model.fileName);
        string pathToThumbs = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/thumbs"), thumbname + ".jpg");
        string finalPath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/flv"), model.fileName);
        string thumbPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/thumbs");
        string vidDuration = "";
        string videoDurationSec = "";

        int maxWidth = 380;
        int maxHeight = 360;

        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(sourceFilePath, model.data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        var ffMpegThumb = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();

        ffMpegThumb.GetVideoThumbnail(sourceFilePath, pathToThumbs);

        var ffmpegVid = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();

        ffmpegVid.ConvertMedia(sourceFilePath, Format.mp4, finalPath, Format.mp4, new ConvertSettings() { VideoCodec = "h264" });

        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
    }

}
```

Is it possible that it's due to my internet connection request gets across late? I'm sending files that aren't even that big in size, they are like 1-2 mbs in size. I wonder how long it will take for bigger files. 
Is there anyway I can improve this process?

Comment: This may not solve your current problem but using ModernHttpClient may drastically decrease your network calls response times. https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient

Comment: How does the time compare when manually posting that BSON content via Postman (or similar tool)?

Comment: the request is instantly received on the server side when I post with fiddler. I'll give ModernHttpClient a try