# Output file using FFmpeg in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, video, xamarin, ffmpeg

I'm building an android app using Xamarin. The requirement of the app is to capture video from the camera and encode the video to send it across to a server.

Initially, I was using an encoder library on the server-side to encode recorded video but it was proving to be extremely unreliable and inefficient especially for large-sized video files. I have posted my issues on another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040102/uploading-files-to-web-api-server-from-xamarin-requests-taking-too-long-to-pro?noredirect=1#comment61630357_37040102)

I then decided to encode the video on the client-side and then send it to the server. I've found encoding to be a bit complicated and there isn't much information available on how this can be done. So, I searched for the only way I knew how to encode a video that is by using FFmpeg codec. I've found some solutions. There's a project on GitHub that demonstrates how FFmpeg is used inside a Xamarin android project. However, running the solution doesn't give any output. The project has a binary FFmpeg file which is installed to the phone directory using the code below:

```cs
_ffmpegBin = InstallBinary(XamarinAndroidFFmpeg.Resource.Raw.ffmpeg, "ffmpeg", false);
```

Below is the example code for encoding video into a different set of outputs:

```cs
_workingDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var sourceMp4 = "cat1.mp4";
var destinationPathAndFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine (_workingDirectory, "cat1_out.mp4");
var destinationPathAndFilename2 = System.IO.Path.Combine (_workingDirectory, "cat1_out2.mp4");
var destinationPathAndFilename4 = System.IO.Path.Combine (_workingDirectory, "cat1_out4.wav");
if (File.Exists (destinationPathAndFilename))
    File.Delete (destinationPathAndFilename);
CreateSampleFile(Resource.Raw.cat1, _workingDirectory, sourceMp4);


var ffmpeg = new FFMpeg (this, _workingDirectory);

var sourceClip = new Clip (System.IO.Path.Combine(_workingDirectory, sourceMp4));

var result = ffmpeg.GetInfo (sourceClip);

var br = System.Environment.NewLine;

// There are callbacks based on Standard Output and Standard Error when ffmpeg binary is running as a process:

var onComplete = new MyCommand ((_) => {
    RunOnUiThread(() =>_logView.Append("DONE!" + br + br));
});

var onMessage = new MyCommand ((message) => {
    RunOnUiThread(() =>_logView.Append(message + br + br));
});

var callbacks = new FFMpegCallbacks (onComplete, onMessage);

// 1. The idea of this first test is to show that video editing is possible via FFmpeg:
// It results in a 150x150 movie that eventually zooms on a cat ear. This is desaturated, and there's a fade-in.

var filters = new List<VideoFilter> ();
filters.Add (new FadeVideoFilter ("in", 0, 100));
filters.Add(new CropVideoFilter("150","150","0","0"));
filters.Add(new ColorVideoFilter(1.0m, 1.0m, 0.0m, 0.5m, 1.0m, 1.0m, 1.0m, 1.0m));
var outputClip = new Clip (destinationPathAndFilename) { videoFilter = VideoFilter.Build (filters)  };
outputClip.H264_CRF = "18"; // It's the quality coefficient for H264 - Default is 28. I think 18 is pretty good.
ffmpeg.ProcessVideo(sourceClip, outputClip, true, new FFMpegCallbacks(onComplete, onMessage));

//2. This is a similar version in command line only:
string[] cmds = new string[] {
    "-y",
    "-i",
    sourceClip.path,
    "-strict",
    "-2",
    "-vf",
    "mp=eq2=1:1.68:0.3:1.25:1:0.96:1",
    destinationPathAndFilename2,
    "-acodec",
    "copy",
};
ffmpeg.Execute (cmds, callbacks);

// 3. This lists codecs:
string[] cmds3 = new string[] {
    "-codecs",
};
ffmpeg.Execute (cmds, callbacks);

// 4. This convers to WAV
// Note that the cat movie just has some silent house noise.
ffmpeg.ConvertToWaveAudio(sourceClip, destinationPathAndFilename4, 44100, 2, callbacks, true);
```

I have tried different commands but no output file is generated. I have tried to use another project found [here](https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg) but this one has the same issue. I don't get any errors but no output file is generated. I'm really hoping someone can help me find a way I can manage to use FFmpeg in my project or some way to compress video to transport it to the server.

I will really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the update on the repository, it says that there is a second package, `Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder` for Android 6.0 onwards.

Install NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder/

```
await Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder
    .For720pFormat()
    .ConvertAsync(inputFile, ouputFile, f => {
            onProgress?.Invoke((int)(f * (double)100), 100);
     });
return ouputFile;
```

For Previous Android versions

Soruce Code https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg
```

Use this as template, this lets you log output as well as calculates progress.

You can take a look at source, this one downloads ffmpeg and verifies sha1 hash on first use.

```
public class VideoConverter 
{

    public VideoConverter()
    {

    }

    public File ConvertFile(Context contex,
        File inputFile, 
        Action<string> logger = null, 
        Action<int,int> onProgress = null)
    {
        File ouputFile = new File(inputFile.CanonicalPath + ".mpg");

        ouputFile.DeleteOnExit();

        List<string> cmd = new List<string>();
        cmd.Add("-y");
        cmd.Add("-i");
        cmd.Add(inputFile.CanonicalPath);

        MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        m.SetDataSource(inputFile.CanonicalPath);

        string rotate = m.ExtractMetadata(Android.Media.MetadataKey.VideoRotation);

        int r = 0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rotate)) {
            r = int.Parse(rotate);
        }

        cmd.Add("-b:v");
        cmd.Add("1M");

        cmd.Add("-b:a");
        cmd.Add("128k");


        switch (r)
        {
            case 270:
                cmd.Add("-vf scale=-1:480,transpose=cclock");
                break;
            case 180:
                cmd.Add("-vf scale=-1:480,transpose=cclock,transpose=cclock");
                break;
            case 90:
                cmd.Add("-vf scale=480:-1,transpose=clock");
                break;
            case 0:
                cmd.Add("-vf scale=-1:480");
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }

        cmd.Add("-f");
        cmd.Add("mpeg");

        cmd.Add(ouputFile.CanonicalPath);

        string cmdParams = string.Join(" ", cmd);

        int total = 0;
        int current = 0;

        await FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFMpegLibrary.Run(
            context,
             cmdParams 
            , (s) => {
                logger?.Invoke(s);
                int n = Extract(s, "Duration:", ",");
                if (n != -1) {
                    total = n;
                }
                n = Extract(s, "time=", " bitrate=");
                if (n != -1) {
                    current = n;
                    onProgress?.Invoke(current, total);
                }
            });

        return ouputFile;
    }

    int Extract(String text, String start, String end)
    {
        int i = text.IndexOf(start);
        if (i != -1)
        {
            text = text.Substring(i + start.Length);
            i = text.IndexOf(end);
            if (i != -1)
            {
                text = text.Substring(0, i);
                return parseTime(text);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int parseTime(String time)
    {
        time = time.Trim();
        String[] tokens = time.Split(':');
        int hours = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
        int minutes = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
        float seconds = float.Parse(tokens[2]);
        int s = (int)seconds * 100;
        return hours * 360000 + minutes * 60100 + s;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this project as well. Same issue, no output is generated at the destination path.

Comment: Your destination path must be a writable path, also please check logs, may be it gives you some error saying can't read file, file already exists or some codec related issue? What command are you trying?

Comment: I'm trying to write the output to external storage which has writable permission set. I can write files to that location but the ffmpeg codec doesn't produce any output to that location. I'm not using the logger and the progress bar. I'll use the logger to see if it produces the right result

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution how to use the ffmpeg? I've the same solution but no out.

Comment: @AkashKava I can't install your package. I'm getting the following error: "Package Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg 1.0.32 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg 1.0.32 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)" Can you update your package?

Comment: @user246392 It is not possible to update due to some limitations in FFMPEG not being compatible with new native android library, for time to time I do look for an upgrade but still haven't found any solution. My package depends on other packages and they are not updated.

Comment: @AkashKava Thank you. On your Github, you mentioned that we should use Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder, but that one is not working for me either. I get the same error message when I try to install that nuget.

Comment: @user246392 I will check, could you please post your error in the same repository?

Comment: @AkashKava Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just figure how to get the output by adding the permission in AndroidManifest file.

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAG