# use FFMpeg in xamarin android

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, xamarin.android, android-ffmpeg

I'm using `xamarin.android` to create an android application. for working on the output of recorded audios in android for changing its pitch and the other thing with [NWaves](https://github.com/ar1st0crat/NWaves/) package, I need to change its format to `.wav`. I tried to use many audio convertors but all of them threw exceptions, but it should work with [FFmpeg](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android). However, I used this code but it doesn't generate any file.

```
List<string> cmd = new List<string>();
        cmd.Add("ffmpeg");
        cmd.Add("-i");
        cmd.Add("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pushersvc/demo.3GP");
        cmd.Add("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pushersvc/test.wav");


        string cmdParams = string.Join(" ", cmd);

        await FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFMpegLibrary.Run(
            Application.Context,
            cmdParams
            );
        return new FileInfo(path);
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066258/output-file-using-ffmpeg-in-xamarin-android) and [FFMpeg](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android) docs, but all of them used `.mp4` convertor.
I also read [ffmpeg doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for audio converting which you can see the code, which is not working